# Round a double to the closest and greater float

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, rounding

I want to round big double number (>1e6) to the closest but bigger float using c/c++.
I tried this but I'm not sure it is always correct and there is maybe a fastest way to do that :

```
int main() {
    // x is the double we want to round
    double x = 100000000005.0;
    double y = log10(x) - 7.0;
    float a = pow(10.0, y);
    float b = (float)x;

    //c the closest round up float
    float c = a + b;
    printf("%.12f %.12f %.12f\n", c, b, x);
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: So, `1.2` should become `2`, right?

Comment: Do you mean the closest larger representable value or the closest larger integer?

Comment: @jrok Where do you get the idea that OP wants rounding to integers?

Comment: I mean the closest larger float not integer because i work on number that are bigger than the biggest integer

Comment: @us2012 I meant `2.0`.

Comment: @jrok yes but i work with bigger number

Comment: At first it looked simple, but this is indeed a very interesting question. Care to explain how you got your original solution?

Comment: But still do you mean, the closest larger integer (as in the math definition of integer, ie: whole number)? Or something like 1.234 -> 1.24

Comment: @MementoMori i don't understand, can you give a example with big number (>10^8) ?

Comment: @MementoMori, `float` doesn't have as much precision as `double` therefore if you can for example represent `100000000000000` in `double`, you can't do so in `float`. The closest in `float` could for example be `100000008765440`. It's not at all rounding in the conventional sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply assigning a double to float and back should tell, if the float is larger. If it's not, one should simply increment the float by one unit. (for positive floats). If this doesn't still produce expected result, then the double is larger than supported by a float, in which case float should be assigned to Inf.

```
float next(double a) {
    float b=a;
    if ((double)b > a) return b;
    return std::nextafter(b, std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity());
}
```

[*Hack*] C-version of next_after (on selected architectures would be)

```
float next_after(float a) {
    *(int*)&a += a < 0 ? -1 : 1;
    return a;
}
```

Better way to do it is:

```
float next_after(float a) {
   union { float a; int b; } c = { .a = a };
   c.b += a < 0 ? -1 : 1;
   return c.a;
}
```

Both of these self-made hacks ignore Infs and NaNs (and work on non-negative floats only). The math is based on the fact, that the binary representations of floats are ordered. To get to next representable float, one simply increments the binary representation by one.

Comment: Ah! I didn't realize that `nextafter` was in STL - +1! For details on the implementation of `nextafter`, http://realtimemadness.blogspot.com/2012/06/nextafter-in-c-without-allocations-of.html seems like a good resource

Comment: _one should simply increment the float by one unit. (for positive floats). If this doesn't still produce expected result, then the double is larger than supported by a float_. This is not true. In the example of OP, the next float is about 6000 larger than the double.

Comment: @Shahbaz: in this case, one "unit" would be more than 6000 - it is still the first representable float that is greater than or larger than the double

Comment: @Shahbaz: One float unit (at the point of numbers that large) will be more than 6000, because of the lack of precision. He's quite right that it should work. You can also look at the jsfiddle I posted in my answer which logs everything if you want proof.

Comment: There is no need for the second test and treating infinity specially. When `b` is the largest finite float, `std::nextafter(b, Inf)` returns infinity, simply because infinity is the next representable value after the largest finite value. (Presuming that `Inf` is infinity. I do not see `Inf` in the C++ standard.)

Comment: @larsm and @dave, his `next_after` implementation suggests otherwise. Nevertheless, it would be interesting to know how the unit is calculated.

Comment: @Shahbaz: Here is how the unit (the value of the least significant bit) may be calculated mathematically. For some IEEE-754 `float` value *x*, let *e* be floor(log2(| *x* |)). If 127 < *e*, then *x* is infinity or –infinity, and there is no unit to the next value. If *e* < –126 (including –infinity, if *x* is zero), then the unit is 2^–149 (“^” denotes exponentiation). Otherwise, the unit is 2^( *e* – 23). This is all determined by the fact that the normal exponent range is –126 to 127, there are 24 bits in the significand (23 from top to bottom), and the subnormals clamp the exponent at –126.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen: Regardless of the motivation, the second test accomplishes nothing. Unless `a` is a NaN, the routine would return the same value if `return b;` were used instead of the wasted second test.

Comment: In the "hack", you need to account for the sign, like so: `c.b += c.a < 0 ? -1 : 1;`

Comment: @WenzelJakob: If this is a reason for down vote, please consider that the issue is addressed in the answer in both paragraphs.

Comment: nextafterf() is a much more involved function with various special cases, and hence also slower. It's nice to have this faster hack, but maybe you can edit the post?

Comment: Pedantic: hack relies on `int` endian the same as `float`, something not specified by C/C++ and has occurred in the wild.

Comment: Unclear why code has `a < 0 ? -1 : 1;` with "work on non-negative floats only" qualifier. 
 Hack also has trouble with `-0.0`.

Answer (score 4):

If you use [c99](/questions/tagged/c99), you can use the nextafterf function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>

int main(){
  // x is the double we want to round
  double x=100000000005.0;

  float c = x;

  if ((double)c <= x)
    c = nextafterf(c, FLT_MAX);

  //c the closest round up float
  printf("%.12f %.12f\n",c,x);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can't believe this function exists!

Comment: `INFINITY` should be used rather than `FLT_MAX` in the `nextafterf` expression. Otherwise, this routine will fail to return the next representable value (infinity) after `c` when `c` is `FLT_MAX`.

Comment: Mankka,  `INFINITY` would make this answer even better.

Answer (score 3):

C has a nice `nextafter` function which will help here;

```
float toBiggerFloat( const double a ) {
    const float test = (float) a;
    return ((double) test < a) ? nextafterf( test, INFINITY ) : test;
}
```

Here's a test script which shows it on all classes of number (positive/negative, normal/subnormal, infinite, nan, -0): http://codepad.org/BQ3aqbae (it works fine on anything is the result)

Comment: Subnormals work the same way as other values in this regard. `nextafterf` simply returns the next representable value. There is no need for the loop. Nor is there any need to test for whether infinity has been reached.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Surely if `a` is greater than a float can represent, it will get in an infinite loop without that check? or do you just mean if the loop is removed?

Comment: Nothing is greater than an IEEE-754 `float` can represent, since a `float` can represent infinity. However, my suggestion is to eliminate the loop. A single test suffices, because one application of `nextafterf` will guarantee that the new value exceeds `a` (or equals it if `a` is infinity).

Comment: Given the goal of "Round a double to the closest and **greater** float", this `toBiggerFloat(0)` returns 0. I'd expect a value more than 0.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica since 0 is perfectly representable as a float already it's what you'd typically want (equivalent to ceiling). But for what you're asking, just change `<` to `<=` in the condition (equivalent to floor + delta).