# How can I convert an integer to float with rounding towards zero?

Tags: c++, floating-point, rounding, data-conversion

When an integer is converted to floating-point, and the value cannot be directly represented by the destination type, the nearest value is usually selected (required by IEEE-754).

I would like to convert an integer to floating-point with rounding towards zero in case the integer value cannot be directly represented by the floating-point type.

Example:

```
int i = 2147483647;
float nearest = static_cast<float>(i);  // 2147483648 (likely)
float towards_zero = convert(i);        // 2147483520
```

Comment: An integer (even 64 bits) can always be represented as a floating point. An integer has no fractional part so there is no rounding issue.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie That's not true. The mantissa of floating-point numbers is not large enough to hold all possible integer values.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie How do you represent 64 bits of data  in 32 bits?  You can't.  There will be a lossy conversion

Comment: OK. Maybe I didn't understand the question.

Comment: What means "rounding towards zero"?

Comment: Why is `2147483520` the required "rounded towards zero" result?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie because float cant represent the integers between 2147483520 and 2147483648.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: In IEEE-754 binary32, each finite number is represented as ±d.ddd…ddd•2^e, where d is a binary digit, there are 23 ds after the “.”, and −1022≤e<1024. This equals ±dddd…ddd.•2^(e−23), where we have moved the “.” and adjusted the exponent. When a number represented in this format is 2^24 or greater, e must be 24 or greater. In this case, ±dddd…ddd is an integer and 2^(e−23) is even, so odd integers cannot be represented. As the number exceeds 2^25, 2^26, and so on, 2^(e−23) becomes a multiple of 4, then 8, and so on, further reducing which integers in the range can be represented.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: So, no, not all integers can be represented in a floating-point format. Then consider some number like 16,777,217. It cannot be represented. The two nearest representable values are 16,777,216 and 16,777,218. “Rounding towards zero” means exactly that: When rounding 16,777,217 to produce a value in the binary32 format, we will pick the choice toward zero, so we pick 16,777,216.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, thank you very much for this explanation and example.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52582831/loss-of-precision-for-int-to-float-conversion/52583193#52583193).

Comment: Please refrain from tagging as C *and* C++. This yields an answer for each language (plus some that claim to work for both, often incorrectly so) which are both correct or "acceptable".

Comment: @larkey I doubt this question has an answer independant of a computer language, where I count all instances of assembler code to implement IEEE-754 as a separate language.

Comment: @AlbertvanderHorst Yes, that's why it should be tagged either C or C++, but not both. The answer is language dependent and tagging it as both doesn't make sense.

Comment: I doubt that tagging is the answer. The question should state whether a solution is wanted in general, for C only, for C++ only, for both C and C++,  or for either one of C or C++. Tagging is for searching I presume, and cannot change the meaning of a question. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 27):

Since C++11, one can use `fesetround()`, the floating-point environment [rounding direction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/feround) manager.  There are four standard [rounding directions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/FE_round) and an implementation is permitted to add additional rounding directions.

```
#include <cfenv> // for fesetround() and FE_* macros
#include <iostream> // for cout and endl
#include <iomanip> // for setprecision()

#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON

int main(){
    int i = 2147483647;

    std::cout << std::setprecision(10);

    std::fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD);
    std::cout << "round down         " << i << " :  " << static_cast<float>(i) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "round down        " << -i << " : " << static_cast<float>(-i) << std::endl;

    std::fesetround(FE_TONEAREST);
    std::cout << "round to nearest   " << i << " :  " << static_cast<float>(i) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "round to nearest  " << -i << " : " << static_cast<float>(-i) << std::endl;

    std::fesetround(FE_TOWARDZERO);
    std::cout << "round toward zero  " << i << " :  " << static_cast<float>(i) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "round toward zero " << -i << " : " << static_cast<float>(-i) << std::endl;

    std::fesetround(FE_UPWARD);
    std::cout << "round up           " << i << " :  " << static_cast<float>(i) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "round up          " << -i << " : " << static_cast<float>(-i) << std::endl;

    return(0);
}
```

Compiled under g++ 7.5.0, the resulting executable outputs

```
round down         2147483647 :  2147483520
round down        -2147483647 : -2147483648
round to nearest   2147483647 :  2147483648
round to nearest  -2147483647 : -2147483648
round toward zero  2147483647 :  2147483520
round toward zero -2147483647 : -2147483520
round up           2147483647 :  2147483648
round up          -2147483647 : -2147483520
```

- Omitting the `#pragma` doesn't seem to change anything under g++.
- [@chux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux-reinstate-monica) comments correctly that the standard doesn't explicitly state that `fesetround()` affects rounding in `static_cast<float>(i)`.  For a guarantee that the set rounding direction affects the conversion, use [`std::nearbyint`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nearbyint) and its -`f` and -`l` variants.  See also [`std::rint`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/rint) and its many type-specific variants.
- I probably should have looked up the format specifier to use a space for positive integers and floats, rather than stuffing it into the preceding string constants.
- (I haven't tested the following snippet.)  Your `convert()` function would be something like

  ```
  float convert(int i, int direction = FE_TOWARDZERO){
      float retVal = 0.;
      int prevdirection = std::fegetround();
      std::fesetround(direction);
      retVal = static_cast<float>(i);
      std::fesetround(prevdirection);
      return(retVal);
  }
  ```

Comment: I also agree this is the overall [best approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63196297/2410359), yet even with `std::fesetround(FE_TOWARDZERO)` I do not see C++ as **specifying** that `static_cast<float>(i)` will perform as desired, yet it is entirely reasonable that it should do so.

Comment: Be aware that the GCC implementation has bugs and can ignore the rounding mode changes sometimes: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=34678

Comment: For a facility added in C++11, it would have been nice to specify whether the "environment" meant the entire process or only the current thread. Switching the rounding mode of the entire process is the best way to have weird results in neighbor threads...

Comment: @MatthieuM. Unfortunate oversight in the standard, but on normal real-world implementations (on machines with hardware FPUs at least), the FP rounding / exception settings are per-thread.  (Typically a special CPU register, like x86-64 MXCSR.  This register is part of the context / architectural state of each thread that context switches save/restore.)  IDK if there are any soft-FP implementations where it's global.  (I assume *you* know that, I'm commenting for future readers that this is normally safe in practice.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: I actually only knew for x64; I've never used other architectures so my knowledge is patchy to non-existent when it comes to them. Thanks for confirming that it should behave sanely on typical hardware :)

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I'm not super familiar with many other ISAs, but from a computer-architecture POV it's the only sane design.  A control register shared by all cores would couple out-of-order speculative exec between cores, and be basically unusable for lots of cases (like different cores running different processes).  And would need some special interconnect support for multi-socket systems to make changes on one socket affect others.  Just to make sure, I checked and PowerPC has a FPSCR described as a "user-level register"; AArch64 / ARM32 have a similar FPCR / FPSCR register.

Comment: @MatthieuM. `For a facility added in C++11, it would have been nice to specify whether the "environment" meant the entire process or only the current thread.` I didn't check C++11, but at least the current draft specifies it clearly: `[cfenv.syn] The floating-point environment has thread storage duration.`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica : I agree, and am a little surprised to learn, that `static_cast<float>(<integral type>)` does not claim influence by the current floating point rounding direction.  I've added a bullet about the explicitly influenced `nearbyint()` and `rint()` families of conversion functions.

Comment: Re: "guarantee that the set rounding direction affects the conversion", those functions lack a `float nearbyintf( IntegralType arg )` as needed by OP.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica : OP writes "I would like to convert an integer to floating-point" and provides an example using `float`.  This does not mean OP requires a `float` return, only that the example does.  If `float` is essential, adapt https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294046/round-a-double-to-the-closest-and-greater-float using `std::nextafter(from, to)`, with, in the `FE_TONEAREST` case, conversion back to `double` and comparison of differences to select among the two potential `float`s.

Comment: EricTowers That approach works most of the time yet makes incorrect results due to [double rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Double_rounding) from time to time.  Best solutions only round once, all other math needs to be exact.

Comment: The `convert()` function usually does not work in optimized code (as neither GCC nor Clang support `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON`). The optimized code has statements reordered as `std::fesetround(direction); std::fesetround(prevdirection); return static_cast<float>(i);`. Making some variables `volatile` is a lame workaround.

https://godbolt.org/z/qK1jdf

Answer (score 11):

You can use `std::nextafter`.

```
int i = 2147483647;
float nearest = static_cast<float>(i);  // 2147483648 (likely)
float towards_zero = std::nextafter(nearest, 0.f);        // 2147483520
```

But you have to check, if `static_cast<float>(i)` is exact, if so, `nextafter` would go one step towards 0, which you probably don't want.

Your `convert` function might look like this:

```
float convert(int x){
    if(std::abs(long(static_cast<float>(x))) <= std::abs(long(x)))
        return static_cast<float>(x);
    return std::nextafter(static_cast<float>(x), 0.f);
}
```

It may be that `sizeof(int)==sizeof(long)` or even `sizeof(int)==sizeof(long long)` in this case `long(...)` may behave undefined, when the `static_cast<float>(x)` exceeds the possible values. Depending on the compiler it might still work in this cases.

Comment: The problem is how to detect when `nextafter` is needed. The check `int(static_cast<float>(x)) == x` may result in undefined behavior. Example: `2147483647` to `float` is `2147483648.0f` and back to `int` is undefined behavior as `2147483648` cannot be represented by the `int` type. See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Floating.E2.80.93integral_conversions.

Comment: `int(static_cast<float>(x))` is not defined if `int` is 32-bit and `static_cast<float>(x)` produces 2147483648. C++ 2018 (draft N4659) 7.10 [conv.fpint] 1 says “The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type.” C has similar wording.

Comment: `g++ returns max or min int` Could you quote / link to the documentation that specifies that.

Comment: I changed int(static_cast<float>(x)) to long(static_cast<float>(x)), so there is not problem anymore and this is faster than to do a check

Comment: `static_cast<float>(x)` could already round down (e.g., for `x=(1<<24)+1`), so you should check for `<=` instead of `==` (in case `x` is positive)

Comment: How does `long` help? `sizeof(int)` can be equal to `sizeof(long)`.

Comment: @chtz: That would serve for round down (round toward negative infinity), but the request is for round toward zero.

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes, my comment was only for the case that `x` is positive. Of course, you'll need to check more cases if negative inputs can happen.

Comment: `convert(INT_MIN)` is a problem due to `std::abs`

Comment: `std::abs(long(x))` can have UB if `sizeof(long) == sizeof(int)` and `x = INT_MIN`.

Comment: @chqrlie That could be fixed by flipping the logic, and writing a custom "anti-abs" function that converts positive to negative.

Answer (score 11):

A C implementation dependent solution that I am confident has a C++ counterpart.

---

Temporarily change the rounding mode the conversion uses that to determine which way to go in inexact cases.

> the nearest value is usually selected (required by IEEE-754).

Is not entirely accurate.  The inexact case is rounding mode dependent.

C does not *specify* this behavior.  C *allows* this behavior, as it is *implementation-defined*.

> If the value being converted is in the range of values that can be represented but cannot be represented exactly, the result is either the nearest higher or nearest lower representable value, chosen in an implementation-defined manner.

```
#include <fenv.h>

float convert(int i) {
   #pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON
   int save_round = fegetround();
   fesetround(FE_TOWARDZERO);
   float f = (float) i;
   fesetround(save_round);
   return f;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget about `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON`, otherwise this has undefined behavior.

Comment: The `convert()` function usually does not work in optimized code (as neither GCC nor Clang support `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON`). The optimized code has statements reordered as `fesetround(FE_TOWARDZERO); fesetround(save_round); return (float) i;`. Making some variables `volatile` is a lame workaround.

https://godbolt.org/z/TaPxqa

Answer (score 11):

I understand the question to be restricted to platforms that use IEEE-754 binary floating-point arithmetic, and where `float` maps to IEEE-754 (2008) `binary32`. This answer assumes this to be the case.

As other answers have pointed out, if the tool chain and the platform supports this, use the facilities supplied by `fenv.h` to set the rounding mode for the conversion as desired.

Where those are not available, or slow, it is not difficult to emulate the truncation during `int` to `float` conversion. Basically, normalize the integer until the most significant bit is set, recording the required shift count. Now, shift the normalized integer into place to form the mantissa, compute the exponent based on the normalization shift count, and add in the sign bit based on the sign of the original integer. The process of normalization can be sped up significantly if a `clz` (count leading zeros) primitive is available, maybe as an intrinsic.

The exhaustively tested code below demonstrates this approach for 32-bit integers, see function `int32_to_float_rz`. I successfully built it as both C and C++ code with the Intel compiler version 13.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fenv.h>

float int32_to_float_rz (int32_t a)
{
    uint32_t i = (uint32_t)a;
    int shift = 0;
    float r;
    // take absolute value of integer
    if (a < 0) i = 0 - i;
    // normalize integer so MSB is set
    if (!(i > 0x0000ffffU)) { i <<= 16; shift += 16; }
    if (!(i > 0x00ffffffU)) { i <<=  8; shift +=  8; }
    if (!(i > 0x0fffffffU)) { i <<=  4; shift +=  4; }
    if (!(i > 0x3fffffffU)) { i <<=  2; shift +=  2; }
    if (!(i > 0x7fffffffU)) { i <<=  1; shift +=  1; }
    // form mantissa with explicit integer bit 
    i = i >> 8;
    // add in exponent, taking into account integer bit of mantissa
    if (a != 0) i += (127 + 31 - 1 - shift) << 23;
    // add in sign bit
    if (a < 0) i |= 0x80000000;
    // reinterpret bit pattern as 'float'
    memcpy (&r, &i, sizeof r);
    return r;
}

#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON

float int32_to_float_rz_ref (int32_t a)
{
    float r;
    int orig_mode = fegetround ();
    fesetround (FE_TOWARDZERO); 
    r = (float)a;
    fesetround (orig_mode); 
    return r;
}

int main (void) 
{
    int32_t arg;
    float res, ref;

    arg = 0;
    do {
        res = int32_to_float_rz (arg);
        ref = int32_to_float_rz_ref (arg);
        if (res != ref) {
            printf ("error @ %08x: res=% 14.6a  ref=% 14.6a\n", arg, res, ref);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        arg++;
    } while (arg);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: `i >> 8`, `i += (127 + 31 - 1 - shift) << 23` assume `float` characteristics.  Not unreasonable assumptions, yet not specified by C. `memcpy (&r, &i, sizeof r);` also relies on reasonable, yet unspecified assumptions about `float` size matching `int32_t`and common integers and FP endian.

Comment: I am suspicious about the manual conversion as I'd expect code to mask off the MSbit of the significand in the formation of the `float`.  `i = i >> 8;` look insufficient.  Perhaps `i = (i&0x7FFFFFFF) >> 8;`?

Comment: I'll add language about the assumption that `float` maps to IEEE-754 `binary32`. By my reading that assumption is in the question. The integer bit of the mantissa doesn't need to be masked during combining since the exponent LSB is decremented instead (see comment in code).

Comment: 1) Interesting approach to masking out the implied bit.  2) Even if `float` is IEEE-754 binary32, the endian issue remains - although I find it increasing rare for FP and integer endian to differ. 3) IEEE uses _significand_ not _mantissa_ (subtle differences).  4) UV for a well tested answer.

Comment: Perhaps a good idea to factor out the leading-zero handling to a separate function to make it easy to use GNU C `__builtin_clz` or other intrinsic as a drop-in replacement.  Or just show `shift = _lzcnt_u32(i); i <<= shift;` as a comment.  Oh, you did mention that in the text.  I guess you need sign-extension so you can't just do `i <<= shift - 8;`

Answer (score 6):

A specified approach.

---

"the nearest value is usually selected (required by IEEE-754)" implies OP expects IEEE-754 is involved.  Many C/C++ implementation do follow much of IEEE-754, yet adherence to that spec is not required.  The following relies on C specifications.

Conversion of an integer type to a floating point type is specified as below.  Notice conversion is not specified to depend on rounding mode.

> When a value of integer type is converted to a real floating type, if the value being converted can be represented exactly in the new type, it is unchanged. If the value being converted is in the range of values that can be represented but cannot be represented exactly, the result is either the nearest higher or nearest lower representable value, **chosen in an implementation-defined manner**. C17dr § 6.3.1.4 2

When the result it not exact, the converted value the **nearest higher or nearest lower**?
A round trip `int` --> `float` --> `int` is warranted.

Round tripping needs to watch out for `convert(near_INT_MAX)` converting to outside the `int` range.

Rather than rely on `long` or `long long` having a wider range than `int` (C does not specify this property), let code compare on the negative side as `INT_MIN` (with 2's complement) can be expected to convert exactly to a `float`.

```
float convert(int i) {
  int n = (i < 0) ? i : -i;  // n <= 0
  float f = (float) n;
  int rt_n = (int) f;  // Overflow not expected on the negative side
  // If f rounded away from 0.0 ...
  if (rt_n < n) {
    f = nextafterf(f, 0.0);  // Move toward 0.0
  }
  return (i < 0) f : -f;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Changing the rounding mode is somewhat expensive, although I think some modern x86 CPUs do rename MXCSR so it doesn't have to drain the out-of-order execution back-end.

If you care about performance, benchmarking njuffa's pure integer version (using `shift = __builtin_clz(i); i<<=shift;`) against the rounding-mode-changing version would make sense.  (Make sure to test in the context you want to use it in; it's so small that it matters how well it overlaps with surrounding code.)

**AVX-512 can use rounding-mode overrides on a per-instruction basis,** letting you use a custom rounding mode for the conversion basically the same cost as a normal int->float.  (Only available on Intel Skylake-server, and Ice Lake CPUs so far, unfortunately.)

```
#include <immintrin.h>

float int_to_float_trunc_avx512f(int a) {
  const __m128 zero = _mm_setzero_ps();      // SSE scalar int->float are badly designed to merge into another vector, instead of zero-extend.  Short-sighted Pentium-3 decision never changed for AVX or AVX512
  __m128 v = _mm_cvt_roundsi32_ss (zero, a, _MM_FROUND_TO_ZERO |_MM_FROUND_NO_EXC);
  return _mm_cvtss_f32(v);               // the low element of a vector already is a scalar float so this is free.
}
```

`_mm_cvt_roundi32_ss` is a synonym, IDK why Intel defined both `i` and `si` names, or if some compilers might only have one.

This compiles efficiently with all 4 mainstream x86 compilers (GCC/clang/MSVC/ICC) on the [Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAZugHZEDKqAhgDbYgCMALOQCse5dq3qgA%2BlNTkAztk6oiBBtWz1MAYXTsArgFt6IAMzl1mADIF62AHIGARtlIgArOQAO6WcRX1teoYmnt6%2BDFY29vpOLu7yisoMTESspEQBBkam8dhKfsmpRBF2js5ucilpGUHZlUXWJdFlrgCUcui6pKhcAOQApABMxtaoejgA1H3GmgT6%2BtZEpNYAdEhTuH0ADACCW9s07OisROMLEiQSB0dE56S69KgSrABuAB6u3AM0EAvjrC2TADsACE9uNxgB6CFSfSfAAc4wAXs50JNjAARcYSOYSeREZGkdASDyyCAtKbA8FQ8ZMJi4cayNiiUinRgAWnWV2Of1I2HGDlYmHYAE9xjgfMAbJhxiRxvpnMA%2BQtUWJ0EQkM5xs9ciQKKzZERsILxugaEiUWzsK9DRpluCmEgyEQ2RKkIbpQAFdTKAxs4xi3IEHwMcY2bUs1BIMSK6V0FnbABqAA0TfHkx8BmCsdj4ebCWjMdj9BJ7jgaA1MMTSeTjKCduCYbnngWsTjUM8boTSz5jANcbJxhACehyH9RxIALITiQAMQASgB5ACqtnREgAKguJAAtXCLoGaSfT%2BfL1cSWxb3BJzQ1uvbcG8oideit4vtoiyWSXXsQZ638EAYB1I0Ly2CjuqfKHAA7uMCjYPKjAmmarBajqZB/OwvKCqKQZ/AyTKpOMXJEHsfSAuipE7MRrI3BcxHEqI1g/Ih/xAnegGPs%2BfwUqR5E9G07AgD0rg9OQRg9JsonoEJmgMh0XR8oMxjcKJRBCZJLRtAA1iYrjLNwgLcAAbMYpkDK4cIWdw7iCT0vCifobibGJ6lSUJomyCAzlqRJ/HkHAsAoB0RAeLoRCUNQGD6B4BCcC43BmIQurCHQjAsBwXB8OQUGkKwHhCSpAlCSJLm%2BeQ0n9EM3DjFBxBIOMrxwkZbJGbw4zAKgqDjNwmzLAMqmuZp5AaoKZRkiIQn2eQjmuM54mSeV7lyF55A%2BRp2kmLwyzGEZgLGICgKbICACc8KuLwNlCcYonzW5PQDb5bQBQg8AQCgUUxXFEUQB9sVlKgwA9QM5DluwhqkJ5EAOK55AONYqTCgVolRQhRALvQIowzg%2BjRpwWMELyeTap5ZVWrkYW9CplCMAoMPsAQDi5aQwraDgSOrUsjk9IVIMMMwTKZfwQgJaI4ggFIEgyPTDieZAbToB4iT0CTbILv6bI410awYrIWnCqIWnYGyLzvJ84xsgA6hw7AeXBeSqBA5jVEYCXmMUUQxMIXg%2BErzte6ESvu6U8VyHbSsFFUOiZMIOT2/QEf1JEwcx3UfsJQahRB008VtLI8ndDwRXCTdMMVY1zWte1nXdb1AyDvgxDoUpCXjNo0V/SyzcApoD3rcNRo4C4406b2fWbAMmzGOPB3GLwk%2BAhNdkOU5pULRVHkrWtfnPW9aDoO3X1UD9%2B%2Bff9BCddwp0g7F4OQ9DZVw/QCPsyj3ro5jZXY7jvQLYQhPKMTGGZNUAU3ZgsWmZVpZMxZlgSmqlOZIzaKlfmGUeBC2CKLSQ0gRAM1luNBWSsVZq3NprSMUx0S631qwQ2xs3gZnNlbdgNtQ4JD8GoDQaczAaCzp7BK3swj%2BCjkEPhAc/A8LKOnMO%2BRU5CJdiwnU0jM4NA9hIiohROEZzSOInO7ROgF24EXEqt1Fo9HLi1Nq58uqX2WL1aqEAG66kmFVUcbdT6dyGMYbuvd%2BJtBGoPagRcpozTmqXJanlvKDQ2qPYwcI54DBnoCXglkBjHUXtdVed1vFPUQDvd6J8O7fV%2BnFNAoxow9U2M5UGt9qD3wWo/Z%2B3Nkb71Ru/RGn94Lf3xv/AggDSavHJoaMBNNbILSgQjVmcCOazEQbzNKAs0GCBAMDTB4tsHSzwfLRWfgiHq1IdrChesDZGxNvQy21tbasIdk7WRwg3bKOTiIn2fhOH8MDvc7OMcpFJBkYEORsdw51G0SndRNz06Avebw3O%2BdMqGJLmVMuTVzHjFKeIGuNibH1ySk3Zxrd8lxScb2Lxq1InkBHsYPqSTXDHQ%2BHCUyTUDKLyCSvYx69loRMev5HJeSD7OEKXi/6owJA2CghIVq18wbODvjDepzMX7NLfhjNpv8OniDxp/AmCjekLWAaAxp1NDQjNEmM5mEz2aLGmY0pBfN0p4yykIfgKyJZS1wfATZhChKqzrsbLWIBExJgzBchRVyOGgq4ZYCFqjXnPNDVG8IEaQ7/MUZHX5nzLnx3BUnD5YKQUpuzVo%2BNhddEKULbZIxoTTGV30LIZ4XVnjWL4IOC2ABJWwuAAT2Kxe45SLj%2BVdt4ESreQ0/FjUCcvWaGSTEb3ZX3MlFLLLUu4LSmJRkGW2XSSypag6i79Qnayrd5BwzBiMLwIAA%3D%3D%3D).

```
# gcc10.2 -O3 -march=skylake-avx512
int_to_float_trunc_avx512f:
        vxorps  xmm0, xmm0, xmm0
        vcvtsi2ss       xmm0, xmm0, {rz-sae}, edi
        ret

int_to_float_plain:
        vxorps  xmm0, xmm0, xmm0             # GCC is always cautious about false dependencies, spending an extra instruction to break it, like we did with setzero()
        vcvtsi2ss       xmm0, xmm0, edi
        ret
```

In a loop, the same zeroed register can be reused as a merge target, allowing the `vxorps` zeroing to be hoisted out of a loop.

Using `_mm_undefined_ps()` instead of `_mm_setzero_ps()`, we can get ICC to skip zeroing XMM0 before converting into it, like clang does for plain `(float)i` in this case.  But ironically, clang which is normally cavalier and reckless about false dependencies compiles `_mm_undefined_ps()` the same as setzero in this case.

The performance in practice of `vcvtsi2ss` (scalar integer to scalar single-precision float) is the same whether you use a rounding-mode override or not (2 uops on Ice Lake, same latency: https://uops.info/).  The AVX-512 EVEX encoding is 2 bytes longer than the AVX1.

---

Rounding mode overrides also suppress FP exceptions (like "inexact"), so you couldn't check the FP environment to later detect if the conversion happened to be exact (no rounding).  But in this case, converting back to int and comparing would be fine.  (You can do that without risk of overflow because of the rounding towards 0).

Answer (score 4):

1. Shift the integer right by an arithmetic shift until the number of bits agrees with the precision of the floating point arithmetic. Count the shifts.
2. Convert the integer to float. The result is now precise.
3. Multiply the resulting float by a power of two corresponding to the number of shifts.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution is to use a higher precision floating point for comparison. As long as the high precision floating point can exactly represent all integers, we can accurately compare whether the `float` result was greater.

`double` should be sufficient with 32 bit integers, and `long double` is sufficient for 64 bit on most systems, but it's good practice to verify it.

```
float convert(int x) {
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits
                  >= sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT);
    float  f = x;
    double d = x;
    return std::abs(f) > std::abs(d)
        ? std::nextafter(f, 0.f)
        : f;
}
```

Comment: Re *"As long as the high precision floating point can exactly represent all integers"*: Isn't that [impossible with IEEE-754](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBWAP_8zxaM&t=34m24s)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Why would it be impossible?

Comment: @eerorika: your solution does not work if `sizeof(int) == sizeof(double)`. ie on an architecture with 64-bit `int`, `long`, `float` and `double`. Using `long double` does not help since these can be 64-bit as well.

Comment: @chqrlie Of course not. It works if mantissa is at least the size of the int. The static assert will tell you if the exotic target system is incompatible.

Comment: Unfortunately `std::nextafter` is not as fast as it could be on most implementations, especially for this use case.  You just need an integer decrement of the FP bit-pattern to decrease the magnitude, but a non-inlined `nextafterf` will have to compare its 2 args and check for special cases.  Hmm, maybe I should expand my x86 intrinsics answer to include a SSE2 version that manually inlines the nextafter.

Answer (score 2):

For nonnegative values, this can be done by taking the integer value and shifting right until the highest set bit is less than 24 bits (i.e. the precision of IEEE single) from the right, then shifting back.

For negative values, you would shift right until all bits from 24 and up are set, then shift back.  For the shift back, you'll first need to cast the value to `unsigned` to avoid undefined behavior of left-shifting a negative value, then cast the result back to `int` before converting to `float`.

Note also that the conversion from unsigned to signed is implementation defined, however we're already dealing with ID as we're assuming `float` is IEEE754 and `int` is two's complement.

```
float rount_to_zero(int x)
{
    int cnt = 0;
    if (x >= 0) {
        while (x != (x & 0xffffff)) {
            x >>= 1;
            cnt++;
        }
        return x << cnt;
    } else {
        while (~0xffffff != (x & ~0xffffff)) {
            x >>= 1;
            cnt++;
        }
        return (int)((unsigned)x << cnt);
    }
}
```

Comment: `x != (x & 0xffffff)` is `1<<24 <= x`, and similarly for the negative case.